# What is ordinary, in ordinary least squares?

Tags: regression, linear-model, least-squares, terminology

A friend of mine recently asked what is so ordinary, about ordinary least squares. We did not seem to get anywhere in the discussion. We both agreed that OLS is special case of the linear model, it has many uses, is well know, and is a special case of many other models. But is this really all?

Therefore I would like to know:

- Where did the name really come from?
- Who was the first to use the name?

Comment: It is ordinary because there are other variants now.  Weighted. Robust. nonlinear.   ... Ordinary is how you keep it from being confused with something else.

Comment: As a guess OLS is likely the first numerical fit algorithm [developed circa 1805 AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#The_method). The name ordinary was likely added after variations on the theme were developed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Least squares in $y$ is often called ordinary least squares (OLS) because it was the first ever statistical procedure to be developed [circa 1800, see history](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176345451). It is equivalent to minimizing the $L_2$ norm, $||Y-f(X)||_2$. Subsequently, weighted least squares, minimization of other norms (e.g., $L_1$), [generalized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares), [M Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator#Types_of_M-estimators), bivariate minimization (e.g., Deming regression), non-parametric regression, maximum likelihood regression, regularization (e.g., Tikhonov, ridge) and other [inverse problem](http://iopscience.iop.org/journal/0266-5611;jsessionid=E0E01E0C77698D01C1452EC8FB416175.c4.iopscience.cld.iop.org) techniques and multiple other tools were developed. There is still controversy over who first applied it, Gauss or Legendre (see [link](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176345451)). The term "ordinary" (implying in $y$) was obviously added to "least squares" only after so many alternative methods arose that the (still most) popular OLS needed to be differentiated from the plethora of other minimizations that became available. The word *ordinary* is often used in mathematical jargon as a synonym of *simple*. For example, consider the phrase *ordinary* differential equations. When exactly adding *ordinary*$+$*least squares* occurred would be hard to track down since that occurred when it became natural or obvious to do so. **EDIT** (for @alexis): Early 20th century I would presume, @GeoMatt22 says 1921 in comments below, but the mathematical meaning of *ordinary* (*sive*, vanilla) predates that and certain differential equations were called *ordinary* in the late 18th century as per [The History of Differential Equations, 1670--1950](https://ems.press/journals/owr/articles/765).

Comment: You can also contrast OLS with WLS, weighted least squares, which minimizes the weighted squares.

Comment: Its actually in there somewhat already under "other" norms, for example, $||1-\frac{Y}{f(x)}||$ is weighted.

Comment: This is an old question, if I remember correctly I was really interested (at the time) to figure out who first used the term OLS... Guess I will never know... Good answer tho +1

Comment: I have never heard "least squares" used to describe minimization that is not an $L_2$ norm. (Note that "energy norms" such as used in Tikhonov regularization are just an $L_2$ of a transformed vector.) A more general term would be just "regression", or perhaps "[M estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator#Types_of_M-estimators)".

Comment: I agree with @AdamO that ordinary vs. weighted* seems the likely contrast. (*Rather, ["Generalized"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares). In computational science I think this would still just be called weighted? Why would a weight matrix have to be diagonal?)

Comment: @Repmat [this](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q="ordinary+least+squares"&hl=en&as_yhi=1930) gives a bound perhaps: Top hit is a 1921 astronomy paper using the term consistent with the "vs. weighted" sense.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Fine, I put weighted and the other stuff in, overkill it is, as the list is already full of overlapping terms, for example, where does maximum entropy fit? 1921? Well,  Title: The investigation of the weights in equations according to the principle of the least squares
Author: J Weeder
Is Part Of: PROCEEDINGS OF THE KONINKLIJKE AKADEMIE VAN WETENSCHAPPEN TE AMSTERDAM , 1908, Vol.11, p.142-146 It is lost in time.

Comment: Ah, but what is "normal" about linear least squares: [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)? Or [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Derivation_of_the_normal_equations)? (<--joke) The 1921 was the first that showed up with the phrase "OLS". I figure the phrase had to arise in response, at some time *after* "non-ordinary" variants began showing up. Mathematically, for me the main distinction is in the different linear algebra problems, so ordinary/weighted/generalized/ridge/Tikhonov are much more similar than to each other, vs. L1.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Although OLS and minimum $L_2$ are equivalent, the former is the square of the latter, and, OLS is the square of the minimum $L_2$ norm.

Comment: This answer appears to be speculation. It would be nicer with documentation of the first uses of the phrase, or of a history of it's use.

Comment: @Alexis What I tried for is current use not history. That is, the historic etymology although of intellectual interest is not the first consideration in this case because it's superseded by the semantics, i.e.,  in current math jargon *ordinary*  means *simplest case of*.  That is, a mathematician seeing the word *ordinary* would understand *of the first kind* more in terms of complexity than history. Granted, use of the word does not occur until such a time as there are other *kinds* of the same general thing.

Comment: @Alexis ...For example, it could happen that a more complicated algorithm predates a simpler one, and in that case, the simpler one would be more *ordinary*, i.e., *vanilla*, than the algorithm of the first kind to be developed.

Comment: That ignores "Where did the name really come from?" and "Who was the first to use the name?" which are historical and etymological questions. (Also: I don't disagree with the substance of your answer… I just feel there's way more to be said. Happy new year! :)

Comment: @Alexis The name ordinary as in ordinary differential equations, especially as contrasted with partial differential equations dates from the 18th century. This appears to date from 1741 at the latest in [Euler's work](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1051&context=euler-works) entitled "*Solutio problematum rectivicationem ellipsis requirentium*"

Comment: @Alexis Actually, it is in a modern translation of Euler's work that the concept of ordinary would occur. I don't see the word itself used in the original Latin or the German word by word translation. In any case, by the late 18th century, the word ordinary had taken on its current meaning in mathematics.